# Reworking someone else R code. What is %in%

Tags: r

I am trying to adapt someone else's R code for my needs.

I do not know what this line does:

```
names(train_clean) %in% names(test_clean)
```

I understand names(train_clean).
I understand names(test_clean).

I do not know what %in% is? Looking for help with ? is not helpful in the instance.

```
?%in%
```

> yields Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "?%in%"

Answer (score 0):

Try `?'%in%'`.

It returns a `logical` vector, telling you wether a vector contains one or more of a following vector.
As an example:

```r
c(1:10) %in% c(1,5)
#>  [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```